# Physical interpretation of the Reissner-Nordstrom metric for the special case

Tags: general-relativity, reissner-nordstrom-metric

In the [Reissner-Nordstrom metric](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reissner%E2%80%93Nordstr%C3%B6m_metric)
 $$ \mathrm ds^2 = \left(1 - \frac{2GM}{r} + \frac{GQ^2}{4\pi\epsilon_0 r^2}\right)~\mathrm dt^2 - \left(1 - \frac{2GM}{r} + \frac{GQ^2}{4\pi\epsilon_0 r^2}\right)^{-1} ~\mathrm dr^2 - r^2~\mathrm d\Omega^2$$
 when we consider the case with
$$ \frac{2GM}{r} =  \frac{GQ^2}{4\pi\epsilon_0 r^2} \;,$$

what is the meaning of this case?

Does Electromagnetic force counterbalance the gravitational force?

Answer (score 1):

With a [Reissner-Nordström black hole](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reissner%E2%80%93Nordstr%C3%B6m_metric) there are two contributions to the stress-energy energy tensor, the mass and the electrostatic field.

The mass is all at the singularity at $r=0$ so if we consider a sphere of any radius $r$ all the mass is still inside the sphere no matter how small we make $r$. So all the mass is in effect still pulling you inwards.

However the electrostatic field fills all of space because the field strength vaies as $1/r^2$. This means that for a sphere with some radius $r$ some of the field is inside the sphere and some is outside the sphere. In the RN metric it's the energy contained in the field that curves spacetime, which is why it affects neutral particles. So in effect some of the electrostatic field is inside the sphere and pulling you inwards while the rest of it is outside the sphere and pulling you outwards.

So at the radius $r$ where:

$$ -\frac{2GM}{r} + \frac{GQ^2}{4\pi\epsilon_0 r^2} = 0 $$

the mass plus the energy of the electrostatic field inside $r$ is exactly balanced by the energy of the electrostatic field outside $r$.

Note that it isn't the case that the gravity and the electrostatic force balance because the electrostatic force is the charge times the field strength. So if you have charged particles with the same mass but different charges the forces would balance at different points. The radius $r$ you've described is where the energies of the mass and the field inside and outside $r$ balance.

Comment: Thank you for reply to me.  So the mass includes gravitational, electromagnetic and matter part is it correct?

Comment: @Özcan: in general relativity we don't make a distinction between mass and energy. We take them to be equivalent and related by Einstein's famous equation $E=mc^2$. So although the electrostatic field has no mass it had an energy and that energy behaves like a mass and curves spacetime. The contribution of the electric field is given by the value of the charge $Q$ in the metric. The mass of the black hole $M$ curves spacetime just like any mass and it's contribution is given by the term in the metric containing $M$.

Comment: is it mean that no attracting or pushing force at the radius?

Comment: @Özcan: I've had a go at calculating the gravitational acceleration, and I find that the acceleration is not zero when $-\frac{2GM}{r} + \frac{GQ^2}{4\pi\epsilon_0 r^2} = 0$. In fact I calculate it to be zero at twice this value i.e. at $-\frac{GM}{r} + \frac{GQ^2}{4\pi\epsilon_0 r^2} = 0$