# Can be possible that a neutron star has a negative gravitational surface redshift?

Tags: stars, neutron-stars, gravitational-redshift

I am looking for some strange stars that is gravitationally blue shifted.
A star surface redshift  determines mass-radius relation for chargeless star.
Can be  possible  that a charged neutron star has a negative gravitational surface redshift?

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is no, though the complicated answer is, well, complicated!

The spacetime outside a charged object is described by the Reissner-Nordstrom metric:

$$ ds^2=-\bigl(1-\frac{r_s}{r}+\frac{r_q^2}{r^2}\bigr)dt^2+\bigl(1-\frac{r_s}{r}+\frac{r_q^2}{r^2}\bigr)^{-1}dr^2+r^2d\Omega^2 $$

where:

$$ r_s = \frac{2GM}{c^2} $$

$$ r_q^2 = \frac{Q^2G}{4 \pi \epsilon_0 c^4} $$

From this we can extract the expression for the time dilation at a radius $r$:

$$ \frac{d\tau}{dt} = \sqrt{1-\frac{r_s}{r}+\frac{r_q^2}{r^2}} $$

For an uncharged neutron star $r_q = 0$ and the right side is always less than one i.e. time always runs slower. However once $r_q^2 \gt 0$ this changes the time dilation and in principle it can become greater than one. This would mean that light would be blue shifted.

The problem is that the charge required is so high the neutron star could never be stable. The charge would cause it to disintegrate. So, sadly, there is no way for a neutron star to have a blue shift in the way you describe.

Comment: +1 but would be vastly improved if the final assertion was backed up with a reference.

Comment: Did you mean  r_q^2 \gt  r^2

Comment: @user55944 Specifically I meant $\frac{r_q^2}{r^2}-\frac{r_s}{r} \gt 0$

Comment: all right, is it possible that  matter mass of a star more than total gravitational mass?

Comment: John, What is the meaning of  the zero gravitational redshift $z=0$ for a star. Is it possible?

Comment: @user55944 have a look at my answer to [Physical interpretation of the Reissner-Nordstrom metric for the special case](http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/278916/physical-interpretation-of-the-reissner-nordstrom-metric-for-the-special-case). Basically it means the gravity of the electrostatic field outside the star balances out the gravity of the mass inside the star. But this would require too high a charge to ever be a realistic option.

Comment: Can you give me  references  on the studies of the lower limit of gravitational redshift?

Comment: @user55944: I don't know of any references because I don't think anyone has taken the idea seriously enough to publish on it. As far as we know the charge on astronomical objects is negligable so the situation would never arise. The point is that while the maths may be fun in real life the gravitational shift is always red and always given by the Schwarzschild or Kerr metrics.

Comment: I mean that observational and theoretical  redshift value  in a realistic model without charge

Comment: @user55944: the gravitational red shift is basic GR. See any GR book or [search this site](http://physics.stackexchange.com/search?q=gravitational+red+shift).